# Как угадать следующий AUTO INCREMENT (ID)?

Tags: алгоритм, php, mysql

Перед тем как добавить в базу, нужно узнать следующий `ID` который `AUTOINCREMENT`.

Сделал так:

```
SELECT MAX(id) as maxid FROM tab0

$my_new_id = $db['maxid'] + 1;
```

Строки удалять не собираюсь `DELETE`, удаляю только `UPDATE` колонку `show` перевожу из `true` в `false`. Читал, что так делать нельзя ни в коем случае. Но не могу придумать другой реализации, а перерабатывать структуру не хотелось бы.

- Какие подводные камни этой реализации, если не использовать `DELETE`?
- В каких ещё моментах может "сбойнуть"?

Comment: проблемы будут, когда два пользователя дернут скрипт, он обратиться к базе и получит два одинаковых значения. А потом вставит в базу... Нужно делать этот процесс атомарным.

Comment: Я хочу сыграть с тобой в игру....
Ты должен угадать следующий  AUTO INCREMENT (ID). 30 сек время пошло...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
LAST_INSERT_ID() // получишь последний ID
```

[last_insert_id()](http://www.php.net/function.db2-last-insert-id.php)

Comment: Огромное спасибо, это чем то надежнее моего способа?
-------------------------------------

Comment: Это значительно быстрее

Comment: и безопасней) вы получите айди именно в вашей сессии) т.е. если добавят 2 пользователя одновременно, у каждого будет свой айди(актуально для MySQL 4+ может и меньше, но их я не застал).

Comment: Сие делает не то, что указано в вопросе.

Comment: Сие возвращает последний добавленный ID в базу, а если нужно угадать следующий то тут это глупо т.к. в течении 1с может быть добавлено 10К записей, и что?

Тут вопрос странный, зачем это нужно? т.к. получить следующий явным образом ты не сможешь, только предугадать, но это \+ \- 10К записей :) примерно.

Answer (score 4):

Проблемы вашего решения:

- Не безопасно, из-за многопоточности
- Возможно - отосительно долго выполняется

ID который будет присвоен при следующем (в любой из сессий) `INSERT`:

```
SELECT AUTO_INCREMENT
FROM information_schema.tables
WHERE
  table_name = 'table_name'
  AND table_schema = DATABASE();
```

Не безопасно, т.к. может очень быстро измениться

`last_insert_id()` - вернёт id установленный в последнем insert'е вашей сессии.

Comment: В поле `AUTO_INCREMENT` как раз и хранится *следующий* номер, не текущий. Поэтому нужно не `SELECT AUTO_INCREMENT + 1`, а `SELECT AUTO_INCREMENT`