# как получить id только что созданной записи mysql

Tags: mysql, bash

создаю запись а **id** создастся автоматически

```
export ID=$(cat INSERT INTO tb1 ( title, content ) SELECT title1, content1;)
```

и нужно сохранить **id** в **bash**  *переменную* `export ID`, что дописать в *mysql* запросе ?

Comment: `LAST_INSERT_ID()`

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как угадать следующий AUTO INCREMENT (ID)?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/212969/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%83%d0%b3%d0%b0%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%b4%d1%83%d1%8e%d1%89%d0%b8%d0%b9-auto-increment-id)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вам необходимо в том же соединении с `mysql` вызвать [`LAST_INSERT_ID`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id):

```
INSERT INTO tb1 ( title, content ) SELECT title1, content1;
select LAST_INSERT_ID();
```

Функция `LAST_INSERT_ID` вернёт последний сгенерированный `AUTO_INCREMENT` в этой сессии.